# Error startActivity(intent) al pasar variables a otra activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, programación-móvil

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que necesito pasar variables de una Activity a otra. El problema viene al utilizar "startActivity(intent)", en el que recibo una serie errores que no consigo soluiconar.

Los errores son los siguientes:

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.listadetareas/com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
        at com.example.listadetareas.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at com.example.listadetareas.MainActivity.lambda$-ikeh69DLphwKz0FDw0vt44MpAE(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.listadetareas.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$-ikeh69DLphwKz0FDw0vt44MpAE.onSelectedDayChange(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.widget.CalendarViewMaterialDelegate$1.onDaySelected(CalendarViewMaterialDelegate.java:139)
        at android.widget.DayPickerView$1.onDaySelected(DayPickerView.java:178)
        at android.widget.DayPickerPagerAdapter$1.onDayClick(DayPickerPagerAdapter.java:322)
        at android.widget.SimpleMonthView.onDayClicked(SimpleMonthView.java:1027)
        at android.widget.SimpleMonthView.onTouchEvent(SimpleMonthView.java:372)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.listadetareas, PID: 12082
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.listadetareas/com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
        at com.example.listadetareas.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at com.example.listadetareas.MainActivity.lambda$-ikeh69DLphwKz0FDw0vt44MpAE(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.listadetareas.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$-ikeh69DLphwKz0FDw0vt44MpAE.onSelectedDayChange(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.widget.CalendarViewMaterialDelegate$1.onDaySelected(CalendarViewMaterialDelegate.java:139)
        at android.widget.DayPickerView$1.onDaySelected(DayPickerView.java:178)
        at android.widget.DayPickerPagerAdapter$1.onDayClick(DayPickerPagerAdapter.java:322)
        at android.widget.SimpleMonthView.onDayClicked(SimpleMonthView.java:1027)
        at android.widget.SimpleMonthView.onTouchEvent(SimpleMonthView.java:372)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12082 SIG: 9
```

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val context: Context = this
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    var calendar = findViewById<CalendarView>(R.id.calendar);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener { CalendarView, year, month, day ->
        val date = "$year/$month/$day"


        val intent = Intent(context, AnadirUsuarios::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("year", year)
        intent.putExtra("month", month)
        intent.putExtra("day", day)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}

}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: El error dice que no tienes tu actividad "AnadirUsuario" en tu manifest.

Comment: Gracias! Problema resuelto

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica en el LogCat:

> ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
> {com.example.listadetareas/com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios};
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

en idioma español:

> ActivityNotFoundException: no se puede encontrar la clase de actividad explícita {com.example.talklist /
> com.example.toplist.AddUser}; **¿Ha declarado esta actividad en su
> AndroidManifest.xml?**

indica que debes declarar la Activity AnadirUsuarios dentro de tu archivo [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=es-419)